# How to cancel tests execution if you don't get a url from process.env

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

In the runner class, I can do Cancelling Test Tasks.
How do I cancel test execution if I don't use the runner class?
I need to do it from my code. If env variable is not provided then exit tests
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use process.emit('SIGINT') in this case. Answer from Andrey Belym

Answer (score 2):

You can just press `<Ctrl> + C` in the terminal window while tests are running.

Comment: I need to do it from my code. If env variable is not provided then exit tests.

Comment: So, do you want to cancel a test when this tests is executed? Or do you want to cancel another test, or all the tests when a test is executed?

Comment: @AndreyBelym he means when he has not got env.process dont test because he cant without a url

Comment: You can use `process.emit('SIGINT')` in this case, however I feel that it's better to create a custom runner and do all validation and initialization steps there.